# Assign single value to multiple variables

Tags: c

I want to assign 0 to all declared values in a single statement.

```
char r, g, b = 0;
```

The above only assigns 0 to b but not to the other variables

Comment: I guess the stament is, the above only assigns 0 to b rather than r ?

Comment: Just tested this. You're right. Accepted your edit.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do it two ways:

```
char r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
```

or

```
char r, g, b;
r = g = b = 0;
```

Comment: So this is as terse as it gets?

Comment: @Plenilune Yes, or you should make them static like Sandip suggested.

Comment: NO! Don't make them static. While that _inits_ them to zero, you still have to reinit them if you want them reset, and using static will introduce all sorts of other problems. Your second solution is the right one.

Comment: @Plenilune: C isn't terse enough for you?  8-)}

Comment: Does assignment happen right to left or left to right?

Answer (score 20):

Tersest form is:

```
int r,g,b=g=r=0;
```

Comment: Never saw that before! Finally I know how to get it done in a one liner! (order of `g` and `r` isn't important, right? They just have to be after `b`, right?)

Comment: haha nice one :D @winklerrr the rest after b yeah, order doesn't matter.